# Error with RediSearch operation: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: python, redis, redis-search

I am getting this error while establishing connection with redis-stack-server(I am trying to use redis search). first, I installed redis-cli locally, it was working perfectly fine but when I came to know to use redis-search(because of filters) I have to use redis-stack so I found out about redis-stack-server on docker hub. I ran the docker like this:

> docker run -p 6378:6378 -it redis/redis-stack-server

here are the logs:

```
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.842 * Module 'RedisCompat' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/rediscompat.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> Redis version found by RedisSearch : 7.2.4 - oss
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> RediSearch version 2.8.11 (Git=2.8-7368bb3)
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> Low level api version 1 initialized successfully
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> concurrent writes: OFF, gc: ON, prefix min length: 2, prefix max expansions: 200, query timeout (ms): 500, timeout policy: return, cursor read size: 1000, cursor max idle (ms): 300000, max doctable size: 1000000, max number of search results:  10000, search pool size: 20, index pool size: 8, 
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> Initialized thread pools!
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * <search> Enabled role change notification
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.843 * Module 'search' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> RedisTimeSeries version 11011, git_sha=0299ac12a6bf298028859c41ba0f4d8dc842726b
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> Redis version found by RedisTimeSeries : 7.2.4 - oss
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> loaded default CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES policy: 4096
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> loaded server DUPLICATE_POLICY: block
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> Setting default series ENCODING to: compressed
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <timeseries> Detected redis oss
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * Module 'timeseries' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/redistimeseries.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <ReJSON> Created new data type 'ReJSON-RL'
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <ReJSON> version: 20609 git sha: unknown branch: unknown
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V1 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.845 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V2 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V3 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V4 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <ReJSON> Exported RedisJSON_V5 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <ReJSON> Enabled diskless replication
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * Module 'ReJSON' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <search> Acquired RedisJSON_V5 API
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <bf> RedisBloom version 2.6.11 (Git=unknown)
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * Module 'bf' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisbloom.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.846 * <redisgears_2> Created new data type 'GearsType'
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.847 * <redisgears_2> Detected redis oss
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.847 # <redisgears_2> could not initialize RedisAI_InitError
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.847 * <redisgears_2> Failed loading RedisAI API.
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.847 * <redisgears_2> RedisGears v2.0.16, sha='9559f21d0c3fd6ab4a0edb55d8b89ab125c8cc52', build_type='release', built_for='Linux-ubuntu22.04.x86_64'.
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.847 * <redisgears_2> Registered backend: js.
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.848 * Module 'redisgears_2' loaded from /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgears.so
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.848 * Server initialized
8:M 07 Feb 2024 08:07:33.848 * Ready to accept connections tcp
```

my code:

```
from redisearch import Client as SearchClient
    redis_host = '127.0.0.1'
    redis_port = 6378
    search_client = SearchClient('orderIndex', host=redis_host, port=redis_port, 
    decode_responses=True)
    try:
        info = search_client.info()
        print(info)  
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error with RediSearch operation: {e}")
```

Comment: Redisearch Python client is deprecated and unmaintained. You should use the generic redis client `redispy`